# What's the name of the manga where a group of 3 friends were summoned into another world?

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

There's this manga where a group of 3 friends were talking but all of a sudden, were summoned into another world and were chosen to defeat the world but they needed to check their status.

The first one is a male and became a knight. The second one was a female and I'm not sure who she became but probably also a knight. But the third one, it turned out, wasn't supposed to be there and came by mistake because they were all close together when the portal or gate or hole or whatever came. His status nevertheless became a healer and his teacher was a female healer who came and caught him by force to become part of her group.

Two or three weeks comes by and the two friends (knights) were doing okay but when they came to check on their healer friend, they couldn't find him, but instead a journal. They found out his training went through hell with the banter of student and teacher and both of them were not giving up no matter how difficult the task was.

Answer (score 5):

Could this be *[The Wrong Way To Use Healing Magic](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/feature/2022-09-25/the-fall-2022-manga-guide/the-wrong-way-to-use-healing-magic/.189402)*?

> Usato, an ordinary high schooler, happens to run into two fellow students after school one rainy day. Suddenly, all three of them are engulfed in a magic circle and transported to a fantasy world. There's just one tiny problem—Usato is simply dragged along by accident! On top of that, Usato learns that he is capable of using healing magic—an incredibly rare affinity in this new world. Now Usato must spend his days with the rescue team thugs, struggling through their hellish training regimen—learning the wrong way to use healing magic. Get ready for an eccentric otherworld fantasy filled with comedy and combat!
>
> [image]